# V select dropdown position doesnt look correct

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, select

I am new to UI, in my code using Vue.js and `v-select`. In my select, the width of the dropdown isn't aligned properly (see image below).
I tried adding `autowidth` and `auto` options but it doesn't seems to be working.

```html
<v-select :clearable="false"
    placeholder="Select a schema"
    v-model="queryObj.storage_schema"
    :options="schemaList"
    :reduce="option => option.schema_alias"
    label="schema_alias"
    :disabled="readonlyField"
    auto>
</v-select>
```

[image: Open "select" component with right edge of dropdown misaligned from select box]

Comment: Is it done in vanilla or with a CSS framework ? Did you tried to play with the CSS inspector and add a `width: 100%` to the option list ? Or basically inspect it and find out why this is behaving like that.

Comment: why is this tagged `python`

Comment: Are you using [Vuetify `v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/), or [Vue Select](https://vue-select.org/)? By the styling, it looks like Vue Select.

Comment: If you're indeed using Vue Select, nothing in the code you've provided is causing this behavior, it's something else interfering with or overriding the CSS of the component.